# About posting theorized answer of our own question as an answer

Tags: discussion, answers

According to answers to [another meta question](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331/can-we-ask-question-for-which-we-know-the-answer), it is okay to post questions for which we know to answer, so it follows that we may also answer our own questions. But what if we only have a theorized answer that we do not know correct or wrong? Is it okay to post it as an answer?

I usually include my guts feeling and initial suspicion in the questions themselves, but for [one of my recent questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/differences-between-and-when-counting-occurrences) I could only think up a theory after a few people already answered the question (but none of the answers contain that theory) so I thought maybe modifying the question to include it is a tad late. Plus if I post it as a separate answer I could get feedback to the theory rather than to the question. So I'm almost sure that I should post it as an answer. But just to be safe, I thought I'd better ask around first, hence this question.

So, is it okay to post theorized answer to our own question?

Answer (score 1):

When you post a question, you have to think carefully what your question really is.

If you question is “I encountered this expression, I have some theory/guess why it is in this form, is my thought correct?” then that is the question.  The theory which you are unsure about is part of the question.

Comment: But what if I only thought up the theory after I posted the question? At the time I posted the question I did not have a theory.

Comment: @Lukman: In that case, I think that editing the question and posting an answer are both reasonable options.  If no one has posted an answer, editing the question seems like a much better option, but after someone posted an answer, it can sometimes make an awkward situation if you edit an answer.

Comment: In other words, what you want to do is to add or change the question (whatever the reason is) after some answers have been posted.  That is naturally difficult to handle.  I do not think that there is one solution which can be applied in all such cases.

Comment: I've posted my answer (http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/differences-between-and-when-counting-occurrences/3060#3060) and I believe the length and content of the post warrant it to be there ;)